# Modifying an array of tuples in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and would appreciate any help regarding the following code:

```
var exp = (-3).to(2, 1) 
var out = exp.map(i => java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(math.pow(i, 2).toFloat))
```

Now, I want to write the following code:

```
for (i <- 0 until exp.length)
{if(exp(i) < 0) 
    {out(i) = out(i) >> exp(i).abs}
}
```

that is, I want to modify elements of the `out` vector depending on the elements of the `exp` vector by having a one-to-one mapping between the two vectors. I can't find a single online source which can help me do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra iteration can be avoided by adding the shifting to the lambda function either by `exp(i)` if negative or by `0` (no effect) otherwise, like this,

```
var out = exp.map { i => 
  val f = java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(math.pow(i, 2).toFloat) 
  f >> (if (i < 0) -i else 0)
}
```

Note also

```
def step(i: Int) = if (i < 0) -i else 0
```

so that we can simplify the solution above as follows,

```
var out = exp.map { i => 
  java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(math.pow(i, 2).toFloat) >> step(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
out.zip(exp) map { case (o,e) => if (e < 0) o >> e.abs else o }
```

Answer (score 1):

The vector is **immutable** collection, you can't modify it, but you can create new one. For this, use for yield comprehension:

```
val res = for (i <- 0 until exp.length)
  yield if(exp(i) < 0)
          out(i) >> exp(i).abs
        else
          out(i)
```

or just convert your vector to an array:

```
val out = exp.map(i => 
  java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(math.pow(i, 2).toFloat)
).toArray
```

and modify your array.

Answer (score 0):

Or make the transformation explicit and arguably more readable by putting it in a function then just having a single map operation.

```
def fn(i: Int): Int = {
  val o = java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(math.pow(i, 2).toFloat)
  if (i < 0) o >> i.abs
  else o
}

exp.map(fn)
```